# X-code Print diffrent value of variable in console when varible value is diifrent

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, console, swift5

Thank you for advance to solve my question.

When i print variables in xcode console then i get a diffrent value from exist in variable.

This is my code
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWaxV.png)

And this is my printed value in X-code console
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbwni.png)

how to remove backslash After Single quotation.

Can anyone help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Code, samples and similar should be included as text in the question and not as images. That said, the backslash is an escaped character and what does it matter that it is part of the output? The backslash is not included in the string itself and will not interfere when you use the string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`po` prints the object. If you want to output the string, try `po print(query)`